# How do I combine columns (date, time, year) of a CSV file in the concat format (to create one new date column) and then delete them after?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I am trying to combine three columns from a CSV file which happen to be 'day', 'month', and 'year'. I want to combine them into one 'date' column and then delete them. However, I keep receiving error messages. This is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd 
def airport_data(cur_file, airport_code):
    
    #import data 
    airportsearch = pd.read_csv('/work/Data.airports.csv')
    
    #drop all rows of data that do not belong to the desired airport code 
    airportsearch.dropna([lambda x:
        (x['origin_airport'].isin(['SFO'])) &
        (x)['destination_airport'].isin (['SFO'])]

    #make columns lower case
    airportsearch.columns = airportsearch.columns.str.lower()

    #create new column 
    df = pd.DataFrame(airportsearch, columns=["year", "month", "day"])
    df.dates = pd.to_datetime(df.Year) 

    #drop old columns 
    airportsearch.drop(columns=['day', 'month', 'year'], axis=1)
```

The error that I am getting reads: 'Dataframe' object has no attribute 'Year'. I am unsure what this even means. Any help would be appreciated! Here is the report of the error in case that helps

[image: report of error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you have linked is that "Year" is not a valid attribute of your DataFrame. Python is case-sensitive, and from your code, it seems you've called that column "year".

Also, [please cut & paste error messages as text rather than using screenshots on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)